# VueJS + VUEX - Problems Concerning Data Transfer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuex

My component:

```
<div id="event-picker">
  <template v-for="event in $store.state.events">
    <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="$store.dispatch('prepareEventForm', event)">{{ event.artist }}</a>
  </template>
</div>
```

My store (mutations):

```
prepareEventForm(state, event) {
  state.form.time = event.time
  state.form.date = event.date
  state.form.event = event.event
  state.form.artist = event.artist
  state.form.organizer = event.organizer
  state.form.location = event.location
  state.showForm = true
}
```

The error I get is `Cannot read property 'time' of undefined`

Where could the problem be?

EDIT:

This is my action method:

```
prepareEventForm({ commit }) {
  commit('prepareEventForm')
}
```

Comment: in your `prepareEventForm` method,  `event` is `undefined`

Comment: yes I know that, but how can I fix it !

Comment: Be sure to not pass an `undefined` event in the `dispatch` method. What does `$store.state.events` evaluate to?

Comment: okay, maybe i know the problem, thanks, i will post it, as soon i can

Comment: the events array is initially empty but becomes populated during app usage

Comment: If `$store.state.events` is initially empty, no `<a>` tag should display. Do you call `$store.dispatch('prepareEventForm', event)` anywhere else?

Comment: no i dont ! this is the one and single place

Comment: Show us your actions method. You're dispatching an action.

Comment: it seems vue omits the mutation... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is that the `event` object being passed to your `prepareEventForm` mutation is `undefined`.

This is because when you call `$store.dispatch('prepareEventForm', event)`, it calls your `prepareEventForm` *action*, passing `event` in as the second parameter.

You need to add `event` as the second parameter of your action and pass that as the second parameter in your `commit` call (which is what calls the `prepareEventForm` *mutation*):

```
prepareEventForm({ commit }, event) {
  commit('prepareEventForm', event)
}
```